# Remove brackets split Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, split

I don't think the answer of this problem is very difficult but I just can't get it to work!
I have this div where answers are stored like ("A""B""C") etc. I am reading this div with jQuery so I can calculate the score, so far so good.

Because I need to get each answer individually I am splitting the answers like this:

```
var totalAnswer = $(correctAnswer.split(/A/g).length - 1);
```

Above I calculate the "A" answers and count them.

The problem is that it returns it like this:

`[3]` instead of just `3` without the `[]`. Is there a way I can remove the brackets?

Comment: Could you show your (relevant) mark-up *and* the whole of the relevant JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using jQuery as  `$`? Then why are you using `$()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you're wrapping with jquery object. I'd say you just need to replace

```
var totalAnswer = $(correctAnswer.split(/A/g).length - 1);
```

by

```
var totalAnswer = correctAnswer.split(/A/g).length - 1;
```